# Mixed content error http vs https

Tags: symfony, http, https

I a getting following as error:

```
Mixed Content: The page at 'https://sitename.com/abc/def' was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure script 'http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&libraries=places&sensor=false'. This request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS.
```

My site is built on symfony2 after change in server i started to see this is a lot of pages. I can write script to change all links with http to https but is this right approach to tackle this problem? Are there any other solutions to this?

Also my site is ratings site so i have thousands of pages do recommend solution for big data site.

Comment: Can someone please explain downvote? This is valid question.

Answer (score 3):

If you write your script like so:

```
<script src="//maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&libraries=places&sensor=false"></script>
```

The browser will load with the correct protocol. This goes for images as well. Then if the user comes from http, it will load http, https if https.

Comment: so basically you are suggesting that i should run a script and remove all http & http references in the code?

Comment: I am always wary of recommending wide-spread changes, but I can't think of anything this wouldn't work for. Even if you have <a href="//google.com" it would still take you there just fine, so I can't think of an instance where it would break

Comment: It can break links to resources that has only secure access or only insecure access. Maybe OP has an API service that can handle only HTTP requests but main page will always be secured or vice versa. Then his API will not work.

Comment: I would recommend change only links that are independent of protocol.

Comment: @MichaelSivolobov - What u mean by independent of protocol?

Comment: He is saying there are some api's that will only accept http or https and doing this "//whatever.com" will use the wrong protocol if your main page is the opposite of what it is expecting

Comment: @KevinF - So if i change all to https: wont that be better way to do this then?

Comment: That might get rid of the warning, but I don't know how "correct" that solution is. Someone else will have to speak to that